# What is the difference between the following Qt QStrings which take Json string as input? Using QTcpSockets

Tags: json, qt, qstring, qtcpsocket, qjson

I have a json message to send over a QTcpSocket. Before sending message, the Json message is formatted as below:

Case 1 :

```
//Heartbeat = QString("{\"messageType\":\"Heartbeat\", \"Thread_Name\":%1, \"Heartbeat\":%2}").arg(Thread_Name).arg(HbCount);  //clients Heartbeat
```

Case 2:`

```
Heartbeat = QString("{ \
                    \"messageType\":\"Heartbeat\",\
                    \"Thread_Name\":\"%1\", \
                    \"Heartbeat\":%2 \
                   }").arg(Thread_Name).arg(HbCount);  //clients Heartbeat
```

When QString is ready, it is transmitted over QTcpSocket as below:

```
_pSocket->write(Heartbeat.toLatin1());
_pSocket->flush();
_pSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

On receiving end, The socket able to receive data in both cases. But when received data is parsed using QJsonDocument, Case 1 fails giving empty json doc, where as Case 2 works giving the required JsonDoc.

Here is the receiving end code:

```
QByteArray Data = socket->readAll(); //read data from socket in to a QByteArray

QJsonDocument JsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(Data); //convert QByteArray to QJsonDocument
```

What is the difference between both cases?
What is the best approach between the two?

Comment: what is the difference between case 1 and 2 exactly ?? they look identical !

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gomaa. I resolved it. In the first case, %1 is taking string argument. But Quotes are missing around it. When i added quotes as below, its working good.    `Heartbeat = QString("{\"messageType\":\"DetHeartbeat\", \"Thread_Name\":\"%1\", \"detHeartbeat\":%2}").arg(Thread_Name).arg(HbCount);`

Answer (score 0):

In First Case,  %1 is taking string argument. But Quotes are missing around it. When i added quotes as below, its working good.

```
Heartbeat = QString("{\"messageType\":\"Heartbeat\", \"Thread_Name\":\"%1\", \"Heartbeat\":%2}").arg(Thread_Name).arg(HbCount);
```